# Meaning of "Feds" in Canadian English?

Tags: canadian-english

Examples:

> "Feds will make music downloading illegal, Heritage minister says."

and

> "Feds to look at offering Canadians option to increase CPP
>   contributions"

My best guess is simply Federal Government, I however suspect it might have a more precise meaning.

Comment: Yes this is referring to the Federal Government.

Comment: In the U.S. it's often used specifically to refer to the the Federal Bureau of Investigation (FBI). Although it works for both.

Comment: In economics/finance Fed (not Feds) refers exclusively to the US Federal Reserve.

Comment: @snoram - and therefore clearly not relevant to the OPs question, is it?

Comment: Yes. I don't know why we are discussing US English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in Canada, "Feds" means the current federal government, as opposed provincial or municipal governments. Unlike in the US, it means the law makers rather than any law enforcement agency.

Comment: In the US the term refers to a regulatory agency or law enforcement.

Comment: I didn't realize that. Can you give an example of a regulatory agency so called?

Comment: It's common in political articles especially to refer to the source of grant money or regulations as the feds. The FCC is very commonly referred to as 'the feds'. The EPA is another I've seen called 'the feds' quite often.

Comment: I guess that nuance doesn't make it over the border in the TV shows I watch. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what "_feds_" stands for, i.e. the word? Is it a generic reference to the [_central government_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_feds), or is it a specific reference to the [_Members of Parliament_](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=ent&__index=ent&srchtxt=MEMBER+PARLIAMENT) from all the [_Federal Electoral Districts_](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=ent&srchtxt=FEDERAL%20ELECTORAL%20DISTRICT). Do you call "feds" an agent from _Ocean Canada_? Is it about the government or the House? Thank you!

Comment: It refers to the central government, but I don't have a source for any of this. The term includes the bureaucracy as well as the elected representatives.